# azure disconects remote app when it is minimized on the client side

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, minimize, disconnect, remoteapp

We're using a VM from Azure to serve customers via remote app.

The problem we're experiencing is that when a user minimizes or changes to another window other than the window they have from the remote app hosted in the Azure VM, when they go back to it a few seconds afterwards, it says "reconnecting" for some 10 secs, and other times it disconnects and gives the "trying to reconnect" error.

This must be a parameter somewhere that does this on purpose.

On the server side, when this happens, we see sessions be in "idle" state, after the customer waits, the idle state on the server side goes to active and the remote app starts working again.